# Zapier Code Module Python input_data issue

Tags: python, zapier

I am creating a api post request using fields from the zapier email parser and inserting them into the request using the Zapier code Python module.

The problem is that I cant seem to get the input_data fields into the request. The request works correctly until I try inserting those fields.

For example I have an input_data field named "first" for the "firstName" field and when I try to insert it into the data it breaks it, I have tried several different variations brackets, parantheses etc.

I dont have a lot of python knowledge so I am pretty sure its a syntax issue. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Here is the code with the "Api key etc removed" Thanks!

```
 import requests


'Api-Key': 'hidden',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Content-Type': 'application/json', 

    }

    data = '{\n  "arrivalDate": "01/19/2021",  "departureDate": "01/25/2021",  "channelId": hidden,    "arrivalTime": "16:00",  "departureTime": "10:00",  "firstName": input_data("first"), "lastName": "Musetn",  "email": "test@gmail.com",  "phone": "0177123456789",  "notice": "Breakfast, one dog",  "adults": 1,  "priceStatus": 1,  "depositStatus": 1,  "language": "en"}'

    response = requests.post('https://login.smoobu.com/api/apartment/hidden/booking', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: You're not including the value returned from that function, you're putting the literal characters `input_data("first")`.

Comment: so it should be something like        input_data("first", ' ')?

Comment: You need to read up on string interpolation and formatting, you can't put code in a string and expect it to be automatically executed. I'd also recommend using `json.dumps` rather than manually creating JSON strings.

Comment: Thank you I will do some reading up, could you perhaps provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Like the commenter mentioned, you should let python handle turning data into json. Try something like this instead:

```py
import requests
import json


headers = {
    "Api-Key": "hidden",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

data = {
    "arrivalDate": "01/19/2021",
    "departureDate": "01/25/2021",
    "channelId": hidden,
    "arrivalTime": "16:00",
    "departureTime": "10:00",
    "firstName": input_data("first"),
    "lastName": "Musetn",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "phone": "0177123456789",
    "notice": "Breakfast, one dog",
    "adults": 1,
    "priceStatus": 1,
    "depositStatus": 1,
    "language": "en",
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://login.smoobu.com/api/apartment/hidden/booking",
    headers=headers, 
    data=json.dumps(data)
)
```

Comment: Thank I will give that a shot